# Email send with "mailto" not showing in my gmail inbox HTML

Tags: html, mailto

I made a form where you could fill out some details and when you clicked "send" it sent to your email, It worked fine for me but people told me they clicked send but i didn't see anything in my inbox, I hope someone got a solution, Thanks

```
<form action="MAILTO:myemail@gmail.com?subject= Intro request" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Comment: using the _mailto_ just triggers the default mailing app of the client... guess I am right

Comment: is there an alternative? I'm not a very good coder.

Comment: that depends on why this form is being used..

Comment: There could be issues with their mail server blocking your website. Ask them to check their spam folders, but if there's nothing there, try contacting their mail providers to see if your messages are being received.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess i found an alternative.

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP to send email:

HTML form for email input:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
   <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form- control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

When the submit button is clicked, the form will be sent to the server to be processed by php script below.

sendEmail.php:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'query';
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'myemail@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: visitor');
```

Hope this helps